# JavaScript confirm not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, confirm

Below is a code snippet used in the legacy application I am currently working on.

```
var x=confirm("Some Text");
if(x)
 //Call method A
else 
// Call method B
```

It was working fine till some days ago, but now it is not working in Chrome, but still good in IE.

Would it be something to do with the browser update?

Comment: Do you have some kind of ad blocker installed on chrome.

Comment: I have adblock chrome extension installed.

Comment: It might be blocking your confirmation.

Comment: Actually we had a bug last week. This confirmation was being thrown on every user actions (which was the side effect of another bug fix)

Comment: what about firefox..?

Comment: Working good  in ff.

Comment: Any errors thrown? Does the popup just not show up, or does it not register the value correctly? Have you tried logging x and checking if you get correct output? Also, if you have an adblocker installed, you can probably make it log it's actions through the settings, so you can check if it goes wrong there.

Comment: No nothing (no errors). Just now, I tried from our back up site in a different sub-domain. It is working in chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove any ad blocker extension installed to your chrome and try again. Sometimes on applications which have large user base, a few users may mark pop up as ads. This will in turn block pop up/Confirm/Dialogue/Alert for all users who have that extension installed.

I had this problem once. **Ad Block** extension blacklisted alerts in my website.

**NOTE**: After removing extension, please close all instance of chrome. Requires a complete restart of chrome

Comment: Please close all instance of chrome and then try again. (Not just one window, all tabs and windows - Need a complete restart of chrome)