# Chrome dismisses confirm() promps immediately without any user interaction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, confirm

Some users of our website report that `confirm` dialog boxes appear, but immediately disappear, as if they are being dismissed automatically. This appears to be affecting Chrome only, not other browsers (not even Chromium).

Searching for similar issues finds many people complaining about `confirm` dialogs within `onbeforeunload`, but that is not my issue: this is *not* in that situation. The `confirm` dialog is shown when the page initially loads (triggered by jQuery `$(document).ready()`).

The [Chrome documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy) shows that `confirm` will not activate its tab and will be dismissed when the tab is switched from. That’s fine: the tab is already active (the `confirm` dialog appears on page load), and I am happy for it to be dismissed when the tab is switched from. The issue is that it’s being dismissed immediately, without any user interaction.

I found [one similar report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34063030), but in that case the `confirm` prompts never appeared in the first place. It looks like what we’re seeing is something different.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var c = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this entry?');
if (c) {
    $.ajax(
        '/api/show/competition/delete',
        {
            'method': 'POST',
            'data': { 'id' : 9 },
            'dataType': 'json',
            'complete': function(response, status) {
                if (response.responseJSON.error) {
                    alert(response.responseJSON.message);
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    document.location.href = "/show/application/competition";
                }
            }
        }
    );
} else {
    document.location.href = "/show/application/competition/entry/9";
}
});
```

---

We could use a jQuery modal window if necessary, but it seems silly to use an entire library to replace one line of code. And native browser alerts tend to look better in mobile browsers anyway.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a pop up blocker or chrome blocking it since no user action was triggered to show the prompt.

Comment: In your link, the problem solved by _removing some extensions and then_ restart the browser. Are you sure it isn't the problem in this issue (maybe they have ad blockers)?

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly same issue. It seems like a chrome issue.

It requires a trick. 
In my case, it worked by putting 0.1 sec delay with setTimeout function.

Try this. It will work.

```
function doConfirm() {
  var c = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this entry?');
  if (c) {
    $.ajax(
        '/api/show/competition/delete',
        {
            'method': 'POST',
            'data': { 'id' : 9 },
            'dataType': 'json',
            'complete': function(response, status) {
                if (response.responseJSON.error) {
                    alert(response.responseJSON.message);
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    document.location.href = "/show/application/competition";
                }
            }
        }
    );
  } else {
    document.location.href = "/show/application/competition/entry/9";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ doConfirm() }, 100);    
});
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Appreciated.

Comment: Having this issue caused by an iFrame, this doesn't always work, it depends on the iFrame loading time (or at least I think so), so it is not a viable solution.

Comment: Thank you. It was driving me crazy. I spent half a night trying to fashion up a modal dialog using DIV and was hating it. My use case was simple - alert the user they need to enter email address. but it kept disappearing on chrome. This delay fixed the issue.

Comment: I agree with @Silencer here. Chrome seems to have this bug for quite a while now and as per my understanding when a page / iframe is navigated to a different location, chrome seems to be dismissing any active dialogs (`alert`, `confirm`, `prompt`) without any user interaction. As we can't be so sure about the exact load/navigate timings of any iframe, `setTimeout` even though looks to be having solved this issue, will break some day for sure. (Unless I am missing something)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was caused by an iframe. I had a youtube video iframe, and the alert would close few milliseconds after showing. After removing the iframe, everything worked fine again.

Comment: Having same issue, but I cannot remove the iFrame, can't find a solution.

Comment: Same issue, `setTimeout` with 250 milliseconds worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was appearing for confirm dialog in click event function. Replacing "click" by "mouseup" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Facebook Remarketing Pixel was the source of the problem.

Comment: It seems to be a general problem with Facebook and Twitter iframes on the page. We ended up giving up and switching to a jQuery modal.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more elegant but effective way of adding a timeout is to include a library like [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) and debounce the handler function by ~100ms. If you have an iFrame, it might not be the case but it's definitely an issue without it and this worked instantly for me.

```
$("#my-selector").on("click", _.debounce(handleClick, 100));
```