# Alert Message Box disposing itself rather than the "OK" button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some jQuery and javscript code in my html file. I am displaying an alert message in $(document).ready function. The problem is that the alert message box is disposing itself even I did not click "OK". The box hides itself after almost a second. 
Here is the code summary:

This summarized code works fine when placed independently when placed in a single html file. I have an html file with lots of coding in it and I am unable to find the cause of the error. Can someone tell me why an alert box behaves like this? Could this be a syntax error or something else like a logical error in my code?

I have removed other scripts to test if they conflict with each other.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script 
    src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' 
    type='text/javascript'/>
        </head>
      <body>
            .........rest of the body ...............
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Test");
            });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The alert message box should not disappear without the "OK" button click.

Comment: Please go through this link, it will help you ask better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: We can't see your problem. Maybe should be a video or live demo.

Comment: @dgknca Well here is the link to the page. The alert box is disapperaing. Will you have a a look. Thanks.

https://pixlucente.blogspot.com

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250430/chrome-dismisses-confirm-promps-immediately-without-any-user-interaction

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thanks! I check that too. It is also a similar issue there. I also found out that this issue is caused on Opera. I tested it on Chrome, Edge and Internet Explorer and it worked fine. But still I am unable to get a solution or maybe a trick to ignore this.

Comment: In that question there is an answer that uses `setTimeout`, have you tried it?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes I have tried that too. But it didn't work. Maybe I have a syntax error in my original code. A simple code like the above works also fine on Opera like others.  Maybe Opera is not ignoring a syntax error in my code like Chrome and Edge did.