# Can I tell whether an alert/confirm has been dismissed by the user or by an overzealous ad-block?

Tags: google-chrome, confirm, adblock

Some functionality on our site depends on `confirm` dialogs. Unfortunately, for some users with Ad Block in the Chrome browser, the confirm dialogs are [dismissed immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51250430), meaning that the user does not have the chance to accept them. (Our site contains no ads, and no malicious popups.)

I would like to give such users a link to an alternative method to perform their action, but without putting it in the face of a person who *actually* dismissed the popup themselves.

> Would you like to delete this entry?
>   No.
>   Are you *sure*? Here’s another way you can delete it if that wasn’t working for you.

That would be silly. So I’d like this message to show only if the `confirm` dialog was dismissed without user interaction.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var c = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this entry?');
if (c) {
    $.ajax(
        '/api/show/competition/delete',
        {
            'method': 'POST',
            'data': { 'id' : 9 },
            'dataType': 'json',
            'complete': function(response, status) {
                if (response.responseJSON.error) {
                    alert(response.responseJSON.message);
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    document.location.href = "/show/application/competition";
                }
            }
        }
    );
} else {
    document.location.href = "/path/to/variant/page/with/alternative/delete/method";
}
});
```

See also: [JavaScript confirm not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34063030).

Comment: I may have to work on timing.