# Why isn't my confirmation message working when I try to leave page?

Tags: angularjs

Why isn't my confirmation message working when I try to leave page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <a href="https://w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
        <form novalidate>
            First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
            <br><br>
            <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
        </form>
        <p>form = {{user}}</p>
        <p>master = {{master}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart');


            $scope.master = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };
            $scope.reset = function () {
                $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
            };
            $scope.reset();

            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
                if (!answer) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What routing library are you using?

Comment: Why are you broadcasting `$locationChangeStart`? That event is reserved for the `$location` service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript confirm not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063030/javascript-confirm-not-working-in-chrome).

Comment: using ngRoute for library

Comment: We need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful. In order to provide a solution, we need a full description of the problem. That includes description of what the code did and why this does not achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [onbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) instead.

This will allow you to have a proper confirmation message when the page is about the to unloaded (or what you call "leaving the page").